# Can I do a forward secure half-round ephemeral-static ECDH?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange

In the context of the project we are working on recently, we would like to enable users to "leave a message" to someone on the Internet securely. Our setting is as below:

- ECC key pairs for open ID
- AES-GCM as session for each message
- Suppose Bob wants to leave a secret message to Alice, whose public key is known to the public.

  1. Alice's key pair is (priv_a, pub_a)
  2. Bob's key pair is (priv_b, pub_b)
  3. Bob generates an ephemeral ECC key pair (epriv_b, epub_b)
  4. Bob computes the shared secret of epriv_b and pub_a
  5. Bob derives an AES-GCM key from the shared secret and creates (epub_b, sig of epub_b using priv_b, encrypted message using AES-GCM key) as M
  6. Bob leaves this message somewhere (could either be public or private) so that Alice could see it
  7. Alice performs the same process to derive the AES-GCM key to decrypt the message and verify Bob

In this scenario, the forward secrecy is not guaranteed. I am curious if we can possibly ensure the forward secrecy under this scenario with only half round of communication (one-sided). If not, is there any alternative that I can adopt to accomplish the goal? Any direction or hint is appreciated.

Comment: I am using ECDH in the whole process as shown in computing the shared secret in step 4 and 7

Comment: What you mean that forward secrecy is not guaranteed?

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee forward security if you still need to decrypt the ciphertext by definition. Kind of obviously you need to maintain a private key to decrypt after all.

Comment: @kelalaka since here only one party is generating an ephemeral key pair for ECDH

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, I understand that so I am actually looking for some alternatives here. Do you have any suggestions if some of the conditions can be relaxed?

Comment: No, not using crypto and 2 entities. However, if you're not trusting Alice to become compromised then you could use a third party provider, and have Alice do more than just use her private key to authenticate. A lot of these things can be *worked around* using general security systems rather than crypto.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah actually maybe I should probably think out of the crypto box. A third party is a good idea but I am not sure if a "trusted" third party can earn enough credit from the users. MPC would be a good option here, by which we can build a trustless third-party CA to conduct additional authentications.

Comment: One possibility would be if Alice were able to publish a 'one-day' ephemeral key each day, and Bob would use that (possibly in addition to Alice's long term key) to encrypt the message; that way, you get PFS outside of that day...

Comment: In this scheme, the "master" long-term key signs a new ephemeral key periodically. However, we will need a trusted proxy to do this for users, shouldn't we? I cannot expect anyone who would like to update such a key each day or even once a week.
Sorry for being stubborn for the PFS or a pure crypto solution to this. I was just too dumb to jump out of it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

> I am curious if we can possibly ensure the forward secrecy under this scenario with only one round of communication.

I do not believe so; the protocol can be summarized as:

1. Alice publishes her long term key
2. Bob does some work (without having Alice do anything)
3. Alice does some work, and retrieves the message

If, anywhere between points 1 and 2, Alice's state was copied, then the copy of Alice's state would be able to perform step 3 just as well as Alice did, and so you don't get PFS.

Also, terminology correction: you asked whether this can be done with only one round of communication; actually, it can, by having Alice send a message at the start of step 2.  Obviously, this doesn't work for your project; what you need is actually a 'half round' exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I've just modified it.

Comment: I am wondering if anyone has done any similar work before for this type of scenario?